# used_memory_rss is too high in redis

Tags: redis

I have Redis instance of which max memory set as 45GB, Used memory is around 40GB and Peak memory usage is 42 GB but RSS is way too high 80 GB.
Is there any way to release this memory.

```
PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
76829 root 20 0 95.3g 80g 1328 R 56.4 63.8 29424:59 redis-server

Memory

used_memory:41960888496
used_memory_human:39.08G
used_memory_rss:86287454208
used_memory_rss_human:80.36G
used_memory_peak:46040101560
used_memory_peak_human:42.88G
total_system_memory:135211622400
total_system_memory_human:125.93G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:48318382080
maxmemory_human:45.00G
maxmemory_policy:allkeys-lru
mem_fragmentation_ratio:2.06
mem_allocator:jemalloc-4.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have very large values(larger than 4k)? it's a possible reason,as it is knonw that jemalloc will waste a considerable amount of memory in that case.

This has been a problem for redis for a long time, as redis can't actually the memory allocation.

A restart can release the memory, but it's not a good way, of course.

Comment: 4k as in 4KB or 4k keys in hash, list or set ?

Comment: @pankaj 4kb for an object

Comment: Now I have removed all object with the size higher than 4k still the RSS value doesn't come down.